# Python display live data processing with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a simple python app which outputs bits on a NRZ-L/NRZ-S numeric encoding.

I want to simulate the "live" data transmission with a speed and a sound frequency.

How could I manage to output live text on a Tkinter text widget with a loop like this ?

```
import winsoud

def show_nrzl(bit_array,frequency,duration):
    for bit in bit_array:
        print bit,
        winsound.Beep(frequency,duration)
    print("")
```

Actually each bit is sent to the python console and I must see if its a 1 or a 0.

Exemple : bit_array = [0,1] with a frequency of 2500 hz and a duration of 300 ms.

Console output:

```
           0                              1
(play Beep at 2500 hz for 300 ms)  (play Beep at 2500 hz for 300 ms)
```

How can I manage to output this live on Tinkter? Can I just embed the python console?

Answer (score 0):

```
def show_nrzl(bit_array,frequency,duration):
    some_text_field_variable.set(str(bit_array))
    #if you want to force an immediate redraw you can do
    root.update_idletasks()
    ...
```

I guess ... its not very clear what your asking

Comment: I tried that and it only display the output when the loop is over.

Comment: see edit ... you should really be handling that function as a callback to something that is non-blocking ... or in a timer update or something ... but in my answer I just put how to force a redraw immediately